# AirPlay on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, video, streaming-video

I would like to start a new project definitely out of my current skill level. I want to make a program to run on the Pi that will allow it to use AirPlay and display on a 2nd gen Apple Tv. This is mostly for a learning experience but also because I have a few practical uses.  For now I would like to display just the console with no GUI. I have a couple questions before I tackle this project.

Is the model B Pi specs good enough to accomplish this?

I ask because I use AirParrot on my Windows box and it consumes roughly 20% of 4.0GB RAM and about 15-20% processor speed on an Intel T9600 2.8Ghz although this is streaming the GUI at the highest quality settings and forcing 720p at 60fps. Most of my programming experience is with web I have a little knowledge with C,Obj C and Python.

Is there a library out for C that allows for capturing the screen for streaming?

Answer (score 1):

This is extremely difficult to do, airplay Raspberry Pi to Apple TV. Only a few people (I am one of them) in the world knows how to do it, so I recommend you not to invest any time unless you really understand the scope of this project.

In order to do mirroring, you need to overcome some encryption algorithm, which is very very difficult.

Comment: Care to explain in more detail what the problems are, and how to overcome them? I personally would be satisfied with emulating an iTunes home shared library, so that I can stream videos to my AppleTV. AirPlay is not neccessary.

Comment: Does AirPlay _require_ encryption?

Comment: I think you've got that backwards huisinro, AirPlay mirroring does not require any encryption but AirPlay (music streaming) does.

Comment: @huisinro I tried looking into rPlay on your website but didn't manage to get anywhere: the product is not buyable, there seems to be demo keys but it's impossible to register on the forum etc.

Answer (score 0):

i think your question is well addressed in this article:

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2013/04/airplaying-music-and-video-from-ipad-to-raspberry-pi-its-as-easy-as/

Comment: I think the TS means the other way around. From Pi to Apple-TV. Not iPad to Pi.

Comment: Correct I want from Pi to Apple-TV although I did find a little bit of helpful information towards the bottom of the article about the protocol.